# Do fields need to be explicitly final to have a "proper" immutable object?

Tags: java, immutability

You often read about immutable objects requiring final fields to be immutable in Java. Is this in fact the case, or is it simply enough to have no public mutability and not actually mutate the state?

For example, if you have an immutable object built by the builder pattern, you could do it by having the builder assign the individual fields as it builds, or having the builder hold the fields itself and ultimately return the immutable object by passing the values to its (private) constructor.

Having the fields final has the obvious advantage of preventing implementation errors (such as allowing code to retain a reference to the builder and "building" the object multiple times while in fact mutating an existing object), but having the Builder store its data inside the object as it is built would seem to be DRYer.

So the question is: Assuming the Builder does not leak the Object early and stops itself from modifying the object once built (say by setting its reference to the object as null) is there actually anything gained (such as improved thread safety) in the "immutability" of the object if the object's fields were made final instead?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken *final* can also help prevent against "reflection attacks" where a rogue programmer would use reflection to access the fields of your class and modify their content.  There was a famous example completely perverting the *String* class and showing that in a lot of cases *String* could actually be modified (if not due to non-finalness btw but due to the fact that once the underlying *char[]* was accessed if was "game over" because you cannot force immutability on an array's content... But that's not my point: my point is that reflection can help do really nasty things).

Comment: @user, in the face of reflection like that, you cannot establish immutability. However, the Security Manager is about making running third party code like that viable.

Comment: wait... If I have a *final* class having a unique *final int* you can modify it using reflection?  My point was precisely that *without* using *final* you cannot prevent against reflection attacks (unless you have a *Security Manager* into place, but it's nearly never the case, which is why I wrote *"in a lot of cases can be modified"*...).  However I'm not sure that you can use reflection to modify a *final int*...  If you can't, then my comment is quite on-topic with your question : )    (I did +1 your question yesterday btw :)

Comment: @user988052, sorry didn't see your comment until now. You can't set a primitive maybe (having to do with it being compiled in as a constant), but you can change an object reference - in 1.5 and 1.6 if it is not static. See http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue096.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you do get "thread safety" from `final` fields. That is, the value assigned to a `final` field during construction is guaranteed to be visible to all threads. The other alternative for thread safety is to declare the fields `volatile`, but then you are incurring a high overhead with every read… and confusing anyone who looks at your class and wonders why the fields of this "immutable" class are marked "volatile."

Marking the fields `final` is the most correct technically, and conveys your intent most clearly. Unfortunately, it does make the builder pattern very cumbersome. I think it should be possible to create an annotation processor to synthesize a builder for an immutable class, much like Project Lombok does with setters and getters. The real work would be the IDE support needed so that you could code against the builders that don't really exist.

Comment: @curiousguy: `volatile` will ensure that the value written by one thread will be visible to another. Without it, a reader, for example, might not clear a value cached in a register and make a read out to main memory.

Comment: "_The other alternative for thread safety is to declare the fields `volatile`_" can you describe the proper way to do that?

Comment: @erickson - A class with fields that are neither `final` nor `volatile` may still be threadsafe as long as the fields are completely initialized during construction and unchanging afterward.  After construction a fully formed object exists in memory and any references to this object must refer to the fully formed object.  Since it doesn't change, there is no posibility for stale values to be seen.

Comment: @Scrubbie Sort of. Such an object has to be "safely published." (For example, the new object is assigned to a *`volatile`* variable, which is read by other threads.) Merely refraining from field mutation is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

An Object can certainly have mutable private fields and still work as an immutable object. All that matters to meet the contract of immutability is that the object appears immutable from the outside. An object with non-final private fields but no setters would for example satisfy this requirement.

In fact, if your encapsulation is right then you can actually mutate the internal state and still operate successfully as an "immutable" object. An example might be some sort of lazy evaluation or caching of data structures.

Clojure for example does this in its internal implementation of lazy sequences, these objects behave as if they are immutable but only actually calculate and store future values when they are directly requested. Any subsequent request retrieves the stored value.

However - I would add as a caveat that the number of places where you would actually want to mutate the internals of an immutable object are probably quite rare. If in doubt, make them final.

Comment: "An object with non-final private fields but no setters would for example satisfy this requirement" - This by itself does not guarantee immutability. Getters can return data member references, and these can be modified by the caller.

Comment: @Eyal: true - though the references themselves would be immutable. If you constructed the object with immutable members then immutability would hold all the way down. Alternatively, creating an immutable composition or collection of mutable objects does make sense in some contexts.

Comment: Should add - different people have slightly different definitions of immutability... mine is "immutability from the perspective of the observer" which I think is the most useful but I've also heard people define immutability as absolutely no change whatsoever allowed.

Comment: @mikera: My preferred definition is that if an object is immutable, replacing the contents of any particular field with *any value which has ever been written to that field*, or doing likewise with any combination of fields, should not affect its validity or state, but may affect is performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just need to consider the environment its running in and decide if frameworks that use reflection to manipulate objects are a hazard.

One could easily cook up an oddball scenario where a supposedly immutable object gets clobbered via a POST injection attack because of a web binding framework that's configured to use reflection instead of bean setters.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can have an immutable object with non-final fields.

For example see java 1.6 implementation of java.lang.String.

Comment: @user988052 Doesn't it break class integrity and program safety?

Comment: @TacticalCoder - Even final fields can be modified via reflection. So the argument that you can have "not-immutable-Strings" is simply untrue, unless one were also willing to say that it is impossible to have an immutable object in Java. The String class, by design, is immutable. Reflection side-steps the design of a class and really isn't relevant in the context of the original question, nor this poster's response.

Comment: @TacticalCoder. Why -1.  Do you think String is mutable? Have you seen it's implementation in 1.6? As with any design philosophy, you either trust your subcontractors, and yourself, to operate equipment and subparts according to operation specs.  If you start to operate outside these specs (such as using reflection on immutable objects) the end result may be similar to Chernobyl -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:
@erickson

Like that:

```
class X { volatile int i, j; }
X y;

// thread A: 
X x = new X;
x.i = 1;
x.j = 2;
y = x;

// thread B: 
if (y != null) {
    a = y.i; 
    b = y.j;
}
```

?

Comment: Thread B isn't guaranteed to see that `y` has been assigned; even though `y` may be assigned "before" B reads it, according to a clock on the wall, there is no memory barrier, so B might read a stale value of `null` from `y`. Here, if you removed `volatile` from `i` & `j`, and put it on `y` instead, B would see "current" values for `i`, `j`, and `y`. This is because writing to a volatile field flushes writes to any field to main memory, and reading a volatile variable refreshes any cached values from main memory.